# Why are these people the Four Gentlemen?

Tags: who-rules-the-world

According to many people throughout the show *Who Rules the World*, Hei Fengxi, Feng Lanxi, Huang Chao, and Yu Wuyuan are popularly known as the [Four Gentlemen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Gentlemen?wprov=sfla1), and have been for some time. Of course, the first two are actually the same person, although this is not widely known. All four are of course talented in supernatural martial arts, so it would make certain degree of sense to group them together—but no one knew this about Feng Lanxi until well after the term had been coined.

From what was publicly known prior to the start of the show, what do these four people have in common that would justify grouping them together?

Hei Fengxi seems to have the reputation of a cold, canny information broker at the beginning of the series, not particularly known for his altruism (a central quality of a *junzi*,) whereas Feng Lanxi was known for keeping to himself and did not seem to have a high profile.

So why are these "four" in particular grouped together by the people as the Four Gentlemen?

Answer (score 1):

Four Gentlemen:

The  'gentlemen' in this drama means a man with good looks, good character, high social status, knowledge, talent, and a good reputation in society.

The 'Four Gentlemen' is ranked Yu Wuyuan, Feng Lanxi,  Huang Chao, and Hei Fengxi. So the ML occupies two seats with his two identities.

In the novel, they have titles to describe their characteristic, which is 'Yu He, Lan Ying, Huang  Ao, Xi Ya' ( 玉和、兰隐、皇傲、息雅) -- One word from the name combined with one word presents his characteristic. These word groups mean 'Yu Wuyuan is mild, Feng Lanxi is secretive. Huang Chao is proud, Hei Fengxi is elegant'. The drama exchanges the titles of ML's two names.

Lan Xi hides his martial arts skills, but he is well-known because of his birth. When he was born, all the orchids in his state bloomed. Even the orchids in the Yong Palace keep blooming all seasons after that. Besides, he's very handsome. So all the civilians in his state like him.

In the novel, he cultivates a unique orchid for FL, which has one black flower and one white flower from the same root, called 'Sacred Jade Moon'. In the drama, the 'Sacred Jade Moon' becomes the name of the flower given by Old Taiyin and the name of the martial arts he founded.

Source: https://mydramalist.com/discussions/try-the-world/72641-world-s-background-setting-introduction

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that the last thing to resolve to make this a perfect answer would be why secretiveness was considered a marker of good character and a good reputation in society.

Comment: Which one of the four is Lan Xi?

Comment: @DavidW - In the show, Feng Lanxi was the "prince" identity of Hei Fengxi (his "spy" identity), one of the two main protagonists. It appears that the opposite is the case in the book.